# where nonstandard WINEPREFIX comes from if I do not have such environment variable?

Tags: wine

When I call `mimeopen --debug prg.exe` it prints:

```
Opening "prg.exe" with A Wine application  (application/x-ms-dos-executable)
wine: invalid directory "/home/myusername/0_home_extension/temp/x" in WINEPREFIX: not an absolute path
```

But I definitely don't have WINEPREFIX environment variable set. So where this `/home/myusername/0_home_extension/temp/x` value comes from?

Answer (score 1):

WINEPREFIX can be an environment variable, but it can also not exist,
since it has a default value.

The Wine User's Guide says
[this](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#WINEPREFIX) :

> Specifies the location of the configuration directory to be used. Use the full unix-style path when specifying. The default wineprefix is $HOME/.wine.

So if WINEPREFIX is not defined, this means `$HOME/.wine`.

However, in your case its value was most likely added by `mimeopen`.
A program can launch a child program and define the environment variables
to be used. In most cases, programs just let the child inherit their
own environment variables, but some programs add some variables.

It's possible that because you haven't specified WINEPREFIX, mimeopen
has created its own internal variable, and didn't do a good job.
It's also possible that this is just a bug in mimeopen.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. There is a mess. How to figure out what configuration file is used here? I mean where is the definition what happens when generic "exe" file is open? I see many wine*.desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications but they seem to be connected to particular installed applications - not a generic exe file.

Comment: Ok, I've hound it in ~/.config/mimeapps.list and have no idea why it is set like this: application/x-ms-dos-executable=wine-extension-itms.desktop which is actually dedicated to iTunes....